# Update data using AJAX and codeigniter failed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to update my data using Codeigniter and AJAX for submit response..

This is my View

```
<form id="form_update" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/update_derap_info" method="POST"  role="form">

   <textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="isi" rows="10" class="form-control" >

   </textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Simpan" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" name="update_info_pemesanan">
</form>
```

My Controller

```
$data = array
    (
        'isi'=> ltrim(rtrim($this->input->post('isi')))
    );
         $this->info_derap->update($this->input->post('id_info'),$data);
         echo'<div class="alert alert-success">Terimakasih, pesan anda sudah kami terima. Pemberitahuan selanjutnya kami beritahunak lewat email.</div>';
         exit;
```

My Model

```
function update($id,$data){
    $this->db->where($this->id, $id);
    $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
}
```

And here is my AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $("#form_update").submit(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#loader").show();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:'POST',
            data:$("#form_update").serialize(),
        }).done(function (data){
            $("#response").html(data);
            $("#loader").hide();
            fillgrid();
        });                        
    });     
</script>
```

I can update My data if I press click submit 2 times, but when I submit just 1 time , it cannot update.

What's wrong?

Comment: check what happens in console on first click of button

Answer (score 1):

You cant update with form. Use this

```
<form  action="" method=""  role="form">

   <textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="isi" rows="10" class="form-control" ></textarea>

   <input type="submit" value="Simpan" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" name="update_info_pemesanan" id="form_update">
</form>
```

in AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#form_update").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#loader").show();
            var editor1= $("#editor1").val();

            $.ajax(
                {
                    type:'post',
                    url:"<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/update_derap_info",
                    data:{editor1:editor1},
                    success:function($data)
                    {
                        $("#response").html(data);
                        $("#loader").hide();
                        fillgrid();
                    }
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

in Controller

```
$text_area = $this->input->post('editor1')
```

So in `$text_area` Contain text which you input in your form

Comment: how if I add new form , (e.g <input type="text" name="additional">). Where's this code will I put in my ajax?

Comment: @FatchulAmin if answer is helpful accept it. So its help to new users without duplicate. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code on your controller:

```
$this->info_derap->update($this->input->post('id_info'),$data);
```

Also, make sure there's a field called `id_info` in the corresponding view.

Comment: I think the point of my case in AJAX. Yes, there is exist about id_info, but I didnt wrote at my question

Answer (score 0):

what a message if you using debug, you can inspect request...

you can insert or adding some javascript function "espace" your request form for example

```
escape($("editor1").val());
```

Comment: `escape()` is a deprecated DOM API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape